# What is the difference between the SECTION element and DIV element in HTML?

Tags: html, web

I've been learning HTML now and I came across two elements with the exact same definition. I want to know what is the difference between the SECTION element and the DIV element.

Answer (score 1):

SECTION is [semantic markup](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) - it has meaning.  You are meant to use it to hold a section of a page.  Other semantic markup tags include `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<nav>` and `<aside>`

A DIV is purely a structural element - it has no implied meaning about what its content is meant to be.

You can style a section using CSS to do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer to the question

The `section` element is a section of the document! Whereas `div` is a container for the elements and to be noted `div` doesnot have any actual meaning in the document.

`section` usage is prohibited if needs to be used a container for the content.

When developer requires to edit or style the document, they are required to be using the `div` tag and not the `section` element.

#### For more

Read the following links to understand more about them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section (Section)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div (Div)